# SQL Query for a key referencing PK

Tags: sql

The question might sound odd but here is a sample table:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| empid | empName | ManagerID |
+-------+---------+-----------+
|     1 | Name1   | null      |
|     2 | Name2   | 1         |
|     3 | Name3   | 1         |
|     4 | Name4   | 2         |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

I want a query which can output employee id name and Manager's name like

```
+-------+---------+-----------+
| empid | empName | ManagerID |
+-------+---------+-----------+
|     1 | Name1   | null      |
|     2 | Name2   | Name1     |
|     3 | Name3   | Name1     |
|     4 | Name4   | Name2     |
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

If a duplicated question exists please direct me to it. I was unable to find it due to my lack of knowledge of keyword for this.

Comment: The term you need is "self join"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  E.empid , E.empName , E2.empName
from TableEmp E
left join TableEmp E2 on E.ManagerID = E2.empid
```